# PL/SQL triggers - calculate percentage

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

I'm struggling with a problem as I'm VERY new to PL/SQL.

I would like to create a trigger to convert a user supplied percentage value, e.g. `10%`.

The column is called `deposit` in my `Booking` table. This booking table also has a total cost. I would like to calculate the deposit amount using the supplied percentage and total cost.

So, when a user types in `10%` (and all the other data) it will do a calculation using total cost and when the record is inserted, instead of showing 10% it shows the deposit amount.

Comment: are you sure that you want to employ a trigger to fill a functionally dependent column in the same table? think about coding that as a view, cleaner design and more efficient (if necessary, use a materialized view).

Comment: Unless there is an explanation why using a trigger is necessary to this equation, I have to -1 the question. I'm always amazed to see the high frequency combination of "I'm very new to PL/SQL" plus "I'm writing a trigger".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I am not sure how exactly your table looks like this may be what you are looking for:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER deposit_perc_calc BEFORE
    INSERT ON booking FOR EACH ROW 
    BEGIN
        :new.percentage := :new.total_cost*:new.percantage/100;
    END;
```

Maybe you should check the Oracle reference for a guide on coding triggers: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/triggers.htm#LNPLS020

Comment: Thank you very much. Worked a treat :-)